# Connecting Netbeans IDE to AWS CodeCommit

Tags: git, netbeans, ide, aws-codecommit

I have just started messing around with AWS_CodeCommit. I'm running on Win10 and will also be running on Ubuntu. I'm attempting to setup a dev environment using NetBeans to connect to a repo on CodeCommit. A google search for this returns no results. Is it possible to connect NetBeans to CodeCommit. I have worked with github in the past (never with NetBeans). I have created an empty repo on CodeCommit but have yet to find a way to connect to it.

The end goal is to have my project on CodeCommit and be able to deploy changes to it from NetBeans.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not running Windows, I was just able to set up NetBeans IDE 8.2 with AWS CodeCommit. These are the instructions.

1. Create your repository with AWS CodeCommit. You can do this through the AWS console or with the AWS CLI using
   `aws codecommit create-repository --repository-name <your-repo-name> --repository-description <your description>`
2. Generate 'Git Credentials' through the IAM console for your IAM user. If you do not have an IAM user already, you will need to create one of those first. Git Credentials are effectively a static username and password that you can set in NetBeans as your username/password. Directions for generating Git Credentials can be found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-gc.html
3. In your new netbeans project, right-click the project and select 'Versioning -> Initialize Git Repository.' Select the directory you want to store the repo locally.
4. Right-click the project again and Git -> Commit. Create an initial commit for your project.
5. Right-click the project and select Git -> Remote -> Push. Choose 'Select Git Repository Location' and set the Repository URL as the CodeCommit repository URL (example: https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/your-repo-name). For 'User' and 'Password', input the User Name and Password you generated in the IAM console. After this, you should be able to select the branch(es) to push, and see it succeed.

Comment: I'm stuck on step 4 when I right click on the project I don't have a Git option.

Comment: I now have the Git option. I had to go to Team > commit from the dropdown menu at the top and after committing i now have a git option on my right click menu of the project.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the jgit JAR (used by Netbeans) is not honoring the credentials helper configuration required by AWS CodeCommit for federated users (non IAM user, with STS tokens for creds). So you can not connect to your repos in CodeCommit as a federated user via the NetBeans Git Plugin. You can however just switch to a shell and use git from the command line. The only thing you really need to do from the command line is "push" and "pull".

Answer (score 0):

I could manage connecting to aws with Netbeans 8.2 following David Jackson answer. I just want to point out 2 subtle things that got me stuck stupidly:

1. be sure to **enter the username and the password leaving out any trailing white space**! No trim will be applied to the textfields in the NetBeans frame. This happened to me since i got the credentials from aws in form of a csv file and copying the cell value (in xls) i got an extra trailing space.
   [image]
2. *if you are running on Windows* and you generate your git credentials of aws multiple times, remember to clear the old cached credentials(Go to Start -> Manage Windows Credentials -> Windows Credentials and you will see a record containing the old (now useless credentials for git)